# How to open the PDF file on emulator?

Tags: android

anybody know how to open PDF file on emulator and add the signature on particular position..please If any one has know please let me know?

Comment: http://zacktutorials.blogspot.in/2014/07/android-downloading-and-viewing-pdf.html

Comment: Make sure AdobeReader is installed in your Emulator/GenyMotion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open pdf file in your android app you can use this following link example

https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview